# insert new record in parent's table instead inserting only on children

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have a parent entity "persona" (people) and two child entities "voluntario"(volunteer) and "colaborador" (colaborator).

I try to add a colaborator to an existing "persona" (because is an existing "voluntario") with this code but entity framework creates one new record on parent's table and one in child's table with the new parent id instead the existing one:

```
// Añadir al colaborador en la tabla de colaboradores.
var persona = db.persona.Find(modelo.donacion.idColaborador);

db.Entry(persona).State = EntityState.Detached;
var colaborador = new colaboradores(persona,modelo.NIF,modelo.cuentaBancaria);

colaborador.personas = persona;
colaborador.idColaborador = persona.id;
db.colaboradores.Add(colaborador);
db.Entry(persona).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

db.SaveChanges();
```

This is the result in table "Colaboradores":

[image: This is the result in table "Colaboradores":]

This is the result in table "Personas":
[image: This is the result in table "Personas"]

And finally, this is my Entity Model (edmx):
[image: EntyModel]

Thanks in advance for your help. Best regards,

Joaquín

Answer (score 0):

change `db.colaboradores.Add(colaborador)`
to `db.Entry(colaborador).State = EntityState.Added`
Leave the other states alone. EF is smart enough to understand the relationships and handles it for you.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but unfortunately it doesn't work. It shows an exception (InvalidOperationException) with message: "collection modified enumeration may not execute"

Comment: did you detach the "persona"?

Comment: If I detach "persona", it creates a new row with new id in "persona" and "colaborador", and if I comment this line: "db.Entry(persona).State = EntityState.Detached;", it shows the exception. Thanks for your time.

Comment: put the state to Modified

Comment: I changed and it throws a new exception while executing db.SaveChanges(); saying "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded."

Comment: Yes @AntLaC, I think the issue is due to the base() call on the routine new colaboradores(), but I am not sure how to solve it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back you, I had to get some sleep :)
Question, is there a reason you are using HashSet over DbSet?
In your creation of the new colaboradores you are actually creating a new persona in the sense of EF. The next step I would attempt is to do your find like you are and then copying the properties to it from the new colaboradores

Comment: I added the code editing the last answer to copy the properties, but it doesn't create the new row in colaboradores. The reason to use HashSet is because I used Database First and Visual Studio created the default constructor with HashSet instead of DbSet. Please, can you post your solution in a new answer? Thank you very much and no problem for sleeping during a time

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 constructors:

```
/// <summary>
/// Constructor por defecto
/// </summary>
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
public colaboradores() : base()
{
    this.donaciones = new HashSet<donaciones>();
}

/// <summary>
/// Constructor por parámetros de Colaboradores. Hereda de Persona
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ident">ID Autoincremental de la persona</param>
/// <param name="name">Nombre de la persona</param>
/// <param name="lastName">Apellidos de una persona</param>
/// <param name="postalAddress">Dirección postal de la persona</param>
/// <param name="postalCode">Codigo postal de la dirección postal de la persona</param>
/// <param name="city">Localidad de la persona</param>
/// <param name="state">Provincia correspondiente a la localidad de una persona</param>
/// <param name="country">Pais de la dirección postal de la persona</param>
/// <param name="phone1">Teléfono de contacto de la persona</param>
/// <param name="phone2">Teléfono de contacto secundario de la persona. Valor opcional y no requerido en los formularios.</param>
/// <param name="emailAddress">Dirección de correo electrónico de la persona.</param>
/// <param name="birthDate">Fecha de Nacimiento de la persona. Valor opcional no requerido en los formularios.</param>
/// <param name="CIF_NIF">Número de identificación fiscal de la persona o empresa que es colaborador.</param>
/// <param name="cuentaBancaria">Cuenta bancaria a dónde se realizarán los cargos de las donaciones.</param>

public colaboradores(int ident, string name, string lastName, string postalAddress, string postalCode, string city, string state, string country, string phone1, string phone2,
    string emailAddress, DateTime birthDate, string CIF_NIF, string cuentaBancaria) : base
    (ident, name, lastName, postalAddress, postalCode, city, state, country, phone1, phone2, emailAddress, birthDate)
{
    this.CIF_NIF = CIF_NIF;
    this.CuentaBancaria = cuentaBancaria;
}

/// <summary>
/// Constructor con parámetros para crear el colaborador cuando existe la donación.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="persona">Objeto de la clase persona.</param>
/// <param name="CIF_NIF">CIF o NIF de la persona que realiza la donación (se convierte en colaborador).</param>
/// <param name="cuentaBancaria">Cuenta bancaria a la que se emitirán las remesas bancarias</param>
public colaboradores(personas persona, string CIF_NIF, string cuentaBancaria) : base(persona)
{
    this.CIF_NIF = CIF_NIF;
    this.Cuent`enter code here`aBancaria = cuentaBancaria;
}
```

EDIT: Trying to copy properties in persona:

```
// Añadir al colaborador en la tabla de colaboradores.
var persona = db.persona.Find(modelo.donacion.idColaborador);  
var colaborador = new colaboradores(persona, modelo.NIF, modelo.cuentaBancaria);
persona.colaboradores.Add(colaborador);
persona.colaboradores.First().CIF_NIF = modelo.NIF;
persona.colaboradores.First().CuentaBancaria = modelo.cuentaBancaria;
db.Entry(persona).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

It doesn't create record in child entity "colaboradores".

Thanks